# Read SMS in Android

Tags: android

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" );

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                            uri,
                  new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body" },
                            null,
                            null,
                            SORT_ORDER);
```

In the above code, for example, "body" is content of the message, "address" is the phone number.
So what are "_id" and "thread_id"? Can you give me a example to support explaination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the table which you're querying in the SMS content provider, `_id` is a unique row ID number. It will increment with each message (either sent or received) which is part of that conversation thread. The `thread_id` is a numerical ID for the conversation thread between sender and recipient; this number gets used when a database join is performed between the "messages" table and the "threads" table in the content provider.

Example message exchange:

```
Sender: Hello 1   (_id = 1)
Recipient: Foo    (_id = 2)
Sender: Hello 2   (_id = 3)
Recipient: Bar    (_id = 4)
```

For all of the above `thread_id` = 1, and in the table of conversation threads there will be one entry, for the conversation between "Sender" and "Recipient".  When the conversation thread is displayed in the app, it will do a DB table join between the messages table (your URI above) and the threads table to show only that thread.

Does that help?

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

use like that

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

do{
   String msgData = "";
   for(int idx=0;idx<cursor.getColumnCount();idx++)
   {
       msgData += " " + cursor.getColumnName(idx) + ":" + cursor.getString(idx);
   }
}while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

Please add READ_SMS permission.

Comment: Thread_id is something assigned to the messages coming from same user. So, if you use  thread_id, all the messages from the sender will get and _id is the android auto increment id that is stored in database